# Upload file from Azure Storage to SFTP using Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to upload a file into SFTP using Renci.SshNet within an Azure Function (find at the bottom).
I get a error when this line is executed:
client.Connect();
Error is: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
my user/password/ip/port are correct (I have checked it with Filezilla)
Do you know what could be happening?
Thank you

```
private static async Task<string> UploadFileToSFTP(Uri uri, string sourceFileName, ILogger log )
{
    string storageAccountContainer = "csvfiles4magento";
    string storageConnectionString = BLOBStorageConnectionString;
    string sourceFileAbsolutePath = uri.ToString();
    //SFTP Parameters (read it from configurations or Azure KeyVault)
    string sftpAddress = "address";
    string sftpPort = "port";
    string sftpUsername = "username";
    string sftpPassword = "password";
    string sftpPath = "var";
            string targetFileName = sourceFileName;
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
            if (CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(storageConnectionString, out storageAccount))
            {
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = 
                                   cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(storageAccountContainer);

                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlobToTransfer = 
                cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(new CloudBlockBlob(uri).Name);
                await cloudBlockBlobToTransfer.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
            }

            var methods = new List<AuthenticationMethod>();
            methods.Add(new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(sftpUsername, sftpPassword));

            //Connects to the SFTP Server and uploads the file 
            Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo con = new Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo(sftpAddress, sftpPort, new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(sftpUsername, sftpPassword));
            using (var client = new SftpClient(con))
            {

                client.Connect();

                client.UploadFile(memoryStream, $"/{sftpPath}/{targetFileName}");
                client.Disconnect();
                return targetFileName;
            }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error message?

Comment: Error is: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: Have you configure your sftp server firewall? Besides, could you tell me if you can run the code on-premise?

Comment: Sftp server firewall: its a third party hosting. Conection to sftp with address user name and password works fine with filezilla from my machine. I am not sure how to pass a stream as a parameter in a htrptrigger debugging onpremise (may be using postman?)

Comment: Yes, you can use postman.